# What kind of qualifications would make me eligible to get a ramp operations job in Canada...?

Tags: airline-operations

What kind of qualifications would be required for me to be employed as a ramp agent in Canada..?

Comment: Welcome to Av.SE

Answer (score 3):

Ramp jobs are generally entry-level, with no specific skills required. They can be fairly physical labor, loading & unloading luggage & cargo, pushing baggage carts, driving tugs, belt-loaders, & other vehicles in all weather & without enclosed cabs, so some amount of physical stamina is realistically required.

The ability to show up for work on time is a definite plus.

Don't know what background check and/or drug screen is required for these sorts of jobs in Canada; in the U.S. it isn't onerous & is typically paid for by the employer.

If you're asking about immigration & visa aspects, that's best addressed elsewhere.

Comment: thanks so much..I don't know if you have the answer to this question.. would I be eligible to be employed as an airport operations instructor in canada after moving from Kenya.. What are the requirements..? Thanks..

Comment: Sorry but that is immigration law, and I'm not qualified to discuss how that works for Canada. Not sure if there is a Stack where that would be on-topic or not.